# How to override event handler of a panel's button in YUI3

Tags: yui

I use panel.addButton({value:"XXX",section:...,action:function(){*****}}) to add a button on 
a panel, now I want to override the action of button,how to do this!

Answer (score 1):

You can't "change" the `action` function per se. `action` is a shortcut for adding an event listener for certain events to the button node that you created. What you can do is remove that event listener and add another.

Since `action` only adds one event listener, you can safely remove it by removing all event listeners. Just get the button node with `getButton`, call `detachAll` and attach a new event listener:

```
var panel = new Y.Panel({ /* panel config with some buttons */  });
// later on...
var button = panel.getButton(1);
button.detachAll();
button.on('click', newAction);
```